# How to pass spinner selected item value to autoComplete textview

Tags: java, android

In my app, I have one spinner and autocompleteTextview. I have custom adapter for autocompleteTextview. I want to pass selected spinner item to custom adapter. 
But, i can't pass selected vlaue. If i pass value means automatically get first position value only.

One more doubt: If i disable autocompletetextview then again enable means, I can't type anything in autocompletetextview

Please anyone help me!

Here my code:

Pass spinner value to adapter:

```
autocomplete.setThreshold(1);
autocomplete.setAdapter(new AutoCompleteAdapter(getActivity(),spinner.getSelectedItem().toString());
```

It always pass zeroth position value from spinner.

Enable and disable autocomplete :

```
 public static void autoCompleteTextDisable(AutoCompleteTextView _input){
    _input.setEnabled(false);
    _input.setFocusable(false);
    _input.setClickable(false);

}

public static void autoCompleteTextEnable(AutoCompleteTextView _input){
    _input.setEnabled(true);
    _input.setFocusable(true);
    _input.setClickable(true);

}
```